# jQuery select specific table cells

Tags: jquery

I need to select data from each first `<td> <img>` data tag, process it and then set `<td> <div>` value, I tried like this:

```
 $('tbody >tr').each(function() {
    var tr=   jQuery(this);
    var img = $(tr,'tr > img').attr('data');
    //next setting div value
  });
```

But this doesn't works.

```
  <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>..</th>
               ..
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                           
            <tr>
                 <td> <img data="12"/>'> </td>
                 ..          
                 <td><div id="test"></div> </td>
                 <td>..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            ..
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using `.each()` anyway, do this:

```
$('tbody > tr > td > img').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data');
    //next setting div value
});
```

Or if you need to select the `div` that is nested from each row, do this:

```
$('tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var data = row.find('> td > img').attr('data');
    row.find('.some_div').text(data);
});
```

Comment: should be row.find('#some_div') if id

Comment: @Sergey: Yes, but if an ID, then you should only have one on the page. You can't reuse the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = $(tr,'tr > img').attr('data');
```

should be

```
var img = $(tr).children('td:first-child').children('img').attr('data');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bV6Qf/

Answer (score 1):

Tried like this

```
$('tbody td img, tbody td > div').each(function() {
      //your event handler here
});
```

With that selector your get the two elements that you want the `img` and the `divs` in one selector. So with that you could loop and handle each element